# Sublime: current file in console python

Tags: python, console, sublimetext2

in Sublime console one can execute arbitrary python code. But how can I select the current file buffer to execute commands on it? Like in a "on the fly" plugin.

*EDIT*

I wasn't clear in my question. I don't want to execute the Python code I'm programming, and I'm aware of SublimeREPL. I want to manipulate the text I'm writing (being it code or not) with Python, perhaps using Sublime API, to search, replace, manipulate text and so on just like you would do in a Sublime plugin, but one-off, just like you'd do with Elisp in Emacs.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use [SublimeREPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL), also available through [Package Control](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control/installation). The ST2 console just runs the internal Python version 2.6, and you can't use any third-party modules. SublimeREPL runs any Python interpreter you have installed on your machine, and basically acts just like the command-line version. It utilizes the full syntax highlighting and completion capabilities of ST2, and allows you to transfer bits or whole files of code to the REPL.